# Why am I unable to sniff HTTPS traffic?

Tags: c, windows, https

I implemented a home made sniffer (based on winpcap) and tried to use it to sniff port 443 on TCP connections while browsing HTTPS websites (gmail and facebook), but my code fails to detect any traffic.

I researched what ports are used to establish HTTPS session, and according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure), the default port is 443.

Below is the relevant portion of the code that attempts to detect traffic I am interested in sniffing. The code compiles but I can not see any packets for some reason. I am unable to understand why it isn't working. Is it possible the SSL traffic is occurring on a different port? Is there an error in the code?

```
if( ntohs(tcpheader->source_port) == 443 || ntohs(tcpheader->dest_port == 443))
{
    printf("\nHTTPS:\n");
    for(i=0;i<Size;i++)
    {
        printf("%.2x",Buffer[i]);
        if(i%16==0)
            printf("\n");
    }
          //do some something.
 }
```

Comment: That is port 443 on the server, not on your client. Can you see HTTP connections?

Comment: There is no difference between http and https at the TCP/IP level.

Comment: Question opened after around 8 years. Woah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your homemade sniffer has a bug in how it looks at the port number. Specificaly, when you check the `dest_port`. You are applying `ntohs()` on the result of `dest_port == 443`. You should fix that:

```
if( ntohs(tcpheader->source_port) == 443 || ntohs(tcpheader->dest_port) == 443)
```

The buggy code would almost certainly result in `0` for the other side of the `||`, since the network byte order for `dest_port` is unlikely to ever match `443`.

It is possible to use HTTPS on a port different from 443, but it is unlikely to be a random port. This other port would be specified in the URL in the usual way, but with `https` in the beginning. For example:

```
https://some.server.net:8443/
```

So, it is even possible to use HTTPS over port 80, but I don't know of any webservers that actually check for a SSL client hello, then fallback to in the clear processing.

There is an [extension to HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2817) to allow it to switch to SSL after negotiating with the client in the clear that secure communication is needed. But, this is different from HTTPS.